# How to use more CPU cores for a specific query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

There is a set of materialized views that need to be refreshed daily, problem is that these are taking several hours to run. When checking the RDS console performance insight, it seems it is only using a single CPU core

Optimizing SQL is always important but a reason why this takes a long time is because it does a lot of intersection queries with millions of rows. It's just a lot of data

Is there a way to force it to use more than one CPU to speed up these refresh materialized views?

The code used is simply refresh materialized view myview

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) ? And of course the query itself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name version 13.3

Comment: @FrankHeikens the query is simply refresh materialized view like I said. The queries for the views have thousands of lines of code. running your explain returns Utility statements have no plan structure

Comment: It's not the call to refresh that is interesting, it's the query inside your materialised view. That's the one that takes more than a millisecond

Comment: Postgres 14 can use parallel query for the query part of a `refresh` (not for the INSERT part though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately version 14 doesn't seem to be an option on the dropdown when I try to modify instance. I only get 13.3 and 13.4

Comment: The joys of hosted services...